# How do I backup my Exchange 2010 database using Backup Exec 2010?

Tags: backup, exchange-2010, backupexec

When I try to select my Exchange database (filename.edb) file to add it to the list of items being backed up, it is grayed out with the following message:

```
Not selectable for backup from this node. 
Click the Windows computer icon that lists the Exchange installation.
```

I'm not exactly sure what it is looking for here as this file resides on our primary Exchange server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried any troubleshooting steps yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Two Possibilities

**The first:** If you have installed Exchange 2010 SP1, you need BUE 2010 R2/R3. It should be a free upgrade.

**The Second:** The Exchange Agent either isn't installed or isn't installed correctly. Consider installing the agent and carefully following any instructions. If the agent is already installed (and you're sure you have BUE 2010 R2/R3) then uninstall it, reboot, and reinstall.

Comment: It appears I need to upgrade to BUE 2010 R3. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Job Setup`, select your backup job or the appropriate selection list. Do NOT choose the Exchange database file directly.

*Do you have the Backup Exec Agent for Microsoft Exchange installed/licensed for the Exchange Server?*

If so, you'll want to navigate to the server and select the `Microsoft Information Store` and the relevant database(s).

The selections tree should look like this, assuming the Exchange server is remote to the BackupExec server.

[image]